# View Connected ORGs metadata/data inside the Environment Hub

Tags: managed-package, sandbox, production, environment-hub

I have a question regarding Environment Hub. Somehow, how to view some additional metadata of Connected ORGs inside the Environment Hub ORG.

1. Managing users in all connected ORGs. If the user (probably IDentificator = email of that user) added in two or more connected ORG, I want to know that and see inside Environment Hub ORG. It will be ideal to have the ability to Activate / Deactivate users from Environment Hub ORGs, but it's optional.
2. View additional metadata of Connected ORGs. For example, I want to see available salesforce licences and packages installed with all details of connected ORGs in one place = Environment Hub ORG.
3. I want to build a custom report inside the Environment Hub ORG, but it looks like the "Hub Member" object isn't supported by Custom Reports.
4. Ability to see LAST login date (by any users) to determine when the Sandbox will be deleted.

But if anyone has any idea or different approach on how not to build something custom to solve those issues but use already built by Salesforce or someone, I will be happy to know.